# Directive throw error, not able to understand

Tags: angular, angular5

I use angular5, in the app I create a directive which throw error. I am not able to understand the issue at all any one help me here?

code :

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input, Renderer } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[zoom]'
})
export class ZoomDirective {

    constructor(private el:ElementRef, private renderer:Renderer) { 

        @HostListener('mouseenter') onMouseEnter() {
            this.highlight('yellow');
        }

    }

}
```

error:

```
cannot find onMouseEnter, did you mean onmouseenter
```

there i am getting highlighted at : `onMouseEnter` and `this.highlight('yellow');` what is the issue?

angular cli details:

```
Angular CLI: 1.6.5
Node: 6.11.4
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.2.3
```

Comment: `cannot find onMouseEnter, did you mean onmouseenter` It is literally telling you to use `onmouseenter` instead of `onMouseEnter`. Maybe try that?

Comment: No I tried getting same error, https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives

Comment: The `@HostListener('mouseenter')` should be declared outside of the constructor.

Comment: but getting error at `this.highlight('yellow');` can you update my code as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@HostListener('mouseenter')` should be declared outside of the constructor:

```
export class ZoomDirective {

    constructor(private el:ElementRef, private renderer:Renderer) { }

    @HostListener('mouseenter') onMouseEnter() {
        this.highlight('yellow');
    }

    private highlight(color: string) {
        this.el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = color;
    }
}
```

More examples can be found in the [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives#respond-to-user-initiated-events).